# Google Mail for iOS: How to disable image resizing?

Tags: ios, gmail

I occasionally mail screenshots to colleagues and clients from the official  `Google Mail` app on my iPhone.

Apparently, it automatically scales them down:
[image: Ended up being only a third of the original size]

The image originally was a `1.9 MB` screenshot from the new iPad.

I checked the app and the settings but was unable to find a way to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment you cannot configure this. As an alternative you can use the *native* email app which will ask you if you want to resize large images and let you choose their new size.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a service like Dropbox and mail them the link. A bit less convenient but you'd make sure that no resizing is happening.